# Heatmap not showing much variation due to abundance of low frequency points. How do I make the heatmap produce greater variety of colours?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, heatmap

I have a `location` matrix whose first column corresponds to latitudes and second column corresponds to longitudes. Based on the frequency of occurrence of each row in the matrix, I want to plot a heatmap. This is my code:

```
%3D plot
hist3(location(:,1:2));

% Find unique rows and corresponding indices
[uniqueLocation, ~, n] = unique(location, 'rows');

% Find number of occurrences
nHist = hist(n, unique(n));
mx = max(nHist);

% Create colors for each number of occurrence
colors = jet(mx);
colormap(colors);

% Construct a color matrix
cMatrix = colors(nHist, :);

% Create scatter plot
scatter(uniqueLocation(:, 1), uniqueLocation(:, 2), 25, cMatrix, 'filled');
colorbar('YTick', linspace(1/(2*mx), 1-1/(2*mx), mx), ...
         'YTickLabel', 1:mx);
```

The code does what I want, except that, since it turns out there are a lot of rows that don't occur more than once or twice, and only 1 or 2 rows occurs some thousand times, thus the heatmap has only 1 or 2 points in red, and all other points are blue.

So, how do I bring more variation in colours in the heatmap to be able to show the points that occur 50 times, 100 times, 500 times, etc with different colours, as opposed to all of them being blue now due to being dwarfed by 2-3 points with frequencies of about 10,000? I might be wrong here, but I figured this should be possible by scaling down the high frequency points, so that they become somewhat comparable to the frequencies of the low occurrence rows. But how to do that reliably? Dividing by a constant won't work because that does not change the relative differences. And taking `log` won't work either as all the rows whose which occur 1 time become 0 now, and those that don't occur at all, i.e., have 0 frequency, becomes `-infinity`. So, how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are too lazy to correct each plot by hand with a `caxis` call, you can use [`prctile`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) to get you the upper- and lower bounds of your dataset, i.e. the 0th and 99th percentile in your case. Then plug these in in `caxis` for the limits.

```
lower = prctile(data,0);
higher = prctile(data,99);

caxis([lower higher])
```

Comment: It only made the range of the colorbar smaller (previously 1-48, now 1-11). But it had no change whatsoever in the actual graph, where I still have 2 points in red, and everything else in blue.

Comment: The change your `prctile` range to 95 or something, or whatever work for you.

Comment: Tried that. Still nothing. Went down to `prctile` range 10. But let me ask you to confirm something. The `data` in lower and higher, in my case it is `nHist`, right?

Comment: Yes. Please refrain from using `hist` though; MATLAB will have shown you that is is deprecated and that `histogram` is the new function.

Comment: There is something wrong with my code I think. I checked to see how many elements of each frequency are there, and I found that there were 2 million rows with frequency 1; 20,000 rows with frequency 2; 3000 rows with frequency 3; and so on until 1 row with 48 frequency. So, just to see if different colors would be visible if I remove the rows with frequency 1, I removed all rows with frequency 1. No change in colour. Then I removed all rows with frequency 2 and 3; only 4000 data points removed. Still no change in colour! Could you please check my code and see what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the color axis scaling using `caxis`. If The majority of your points fall between 0-100, and you have a few that are 10000000, then `caxis([0, 100])` will do what you seek. More info in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html)

Comment: It only made the range of the colorbar smaller (previously 1-48, now 1-11). But it had no change whatsoever in the actual graph, where I still have 2 points in red, and everything else in blue.